# Usage of 'have had'

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

The following is a line from the novel 'Atlas Shrugged' by Ayn Rand.

> Why, then—she wondered—should he have had to carry a burden of tragedy which, in silent endurance, he had accepted so completely that he had barely known he carried it?

I have learnt that 'have had' is used when the main verb is 'have' in the present perfect tense. But in the above line, the main verb is 'carry' and 'have had' was used. Please explain this.

Comment: There's quite a lot going on in that sentence. I would look into *have to* as in *I have to go to London next week* and then *why should* as in *why should I fix it when you broke it*. It may then be clearer.

Comment: @Minty I can understand the meaning of both the 'why should' and 'have to' parts.But I am skeptical about the usage of 'have had' in this line.Why shouldn't it just be 'should he have to carry....'?

Comment: 'Why should he have to carry....' implies that he is still carrying it [the burden]. 'Why should he have had to carry....' implies he is no longer carrying it.

Comment: @Charl E Thank you.I understood it.Which part of grammar should I learn inorder to understand these things clearly?(please suggest a source if possible)

Comment: @Moham a very good place to start is this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-have-had

Comment: *Why ... should he **have been obliged to** to carry this burden*, because he ***did*** carry it - because he ***had to*** (in the ***past***). Whereas *Why should he **be obliged to** to carry this burden* refers to ***current*** or ***future*** obligation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["When I have had to break bad news I never know whether I .." or "I never knew whether I ..."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78905/when-i-have-had-to-break-bad-news-i-never-know-whether-i-or-i-never-knew-w)

Comment: have to carry  burden=present tense//have had to carry a burden=present perfect.

Comment: "to have to [do something]" is a phrasal verb which means to be required to do something.  In the present perfect this becomes "have had to".  You could paraphrase this as "Why, then—she wondered—should he have been required to carry a burden. . ."

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to suggest a transition from carrying the burden in the past, to not carrying in the future. That is, the person doing the wondering is looking at something that occurred in the past and projecting it not occurring in the future.

This is related to a major theme of the novel, specifically, people who have accepted an unearned guilt becoming aware of it, and discarding it. This is related to the title of the book.

So the person doing the wondering is asking what the justification for the burden was. This is the "why should he?" part. And, by implication, saying that there was no justification. And so the person with the burden should have long since thrown it off.

Comment: "Have had to carry", have had to is used to express is has been going on for a period of time, from the past to the present.

Answer (score 0):

Sample sentence: Why, then—she **wondered**—should he **have had** to carry a burden of tragedy which, in silent endurance, he **had accepted** so completely that he had barely known he carried it?

**Let's simplify this and put it in the declarative form first**:

She wonder**ed** why he **should have had to carry** a burden of tragedy which, in silent endurance, he had accepted so completely that he had barely known he carried it.

Question form: She wonder**ed** *why he should have had* to carry a burden of tragedy which, in silent endurance, he had accepted so completely that he had barely known he carried it?

**The verb** here is: **should have had to carry**, and not just **have had to carry.** **Notice the inversion**: **should he have had** in the question is "he should have had" in the declarative. The sample sentence is a question.

**should have had** is a modal usage of should, like should have seen, should have gone.

- **Should he have had** to do the work?
- He **should have had** to do the work.

Answer (score -1):

Ms. Rand used the simple past perfect tense.

He had carried his burden for quite a bit it seems--before something dawned on him.